# How can I add component (without import/export to html) in React variable global

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add component (without import/export to html) in React variable global

**Example**

**//HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="App"></div>

      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></scrip   
      <script>
        var App, Search
      </script>

      <script type="text/babel" src="component/App.js"></script>
      <script type="text/babel" src="component/Search.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**//App.js**

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var styles = {
            margin: '0 auto',
            border: '1 px solid red',
            width: '50%'
        };

        return (
          <div style={styles}>
                <h1>sdadasssd!</h1>
                <p>fgfgfgfggf</p>
          </div>
        );
    }
});
```

**//Search.js**

```
var Search = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
    var styles = {fontSize: '1.5em', width: '90%', maxWidth: '350px'};
    return <input
             type="text"
             placeholder="gfgff"
             style={styles}
            />
  }
});
```

How can I add component (without import/export to html) in React variable global

Comment: I have to use <script> var App, Search </script>

Comment: Someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If by add you mean render to html, use:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('App')
);
```

Demo:

```js
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {

        var styles = {
            margin: '0 auto',
            border: '1 px solid red',
            width: '50%'
        };

        return (
          <div style={styles}>
                <h1>sdadasssd!</h1>
                <p>fgfgfgfggf</p>
          </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('App')
);
```

```html
<div id="App"></div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js">
<script>
  var App, Search
</script>

<script type="text/babel" src="component/App.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have to use  <script>
        var App, Search
      </script>

Comment: But demo doesn't. However, I've added it since you seem very attached to it :)